# In an obfuscated Windows Store App, is there any danger in including the Public Debug Symbols?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, obfuscation, debug-symbols, dotfuscator

I have a Windows Store App, currently obfuscated with [Dotfuscator](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview). As of right now, we are not including the public debug symbols in the release package, for fear that they can be used to undermine the obfuscation and possibly assist in reverse engineering/disassembling our application. Unfortunately, this makes it difficult to deal with crash dumps that MSFT provides us.

Is this fear warranted? Should we be including the debug symbols? What are the implications of leaving the debug symbols in?

I've attempted to use the unobfuscated public symbols with the crash dumps, but they do not load in Windbg or the Visual Studio Debugger. I assume because Dotfuscator rebuilds the application.

Is there a way to make Dotfuscator create debug symbols for us to use, and separate those out?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, Dotfuscator's GUI **does** have an option to "Emit Debugging Symbols":
[image: Dotfuscator Professional (Evaluation Software)]

To my knowledge, the Community Edition of Dotfuscator **does not** have this functionality, at the least, I could not find it within browsing the options it provides.  This seems to be confirmed by the *Community Additions* of the [Visual Studio 2005 article on Dotfuscator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227241%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: I am currently using Dotfuscator Pro, so I am able to set it to No PDB. Will the PDB in the package pre-obfuscation be usable post-obfuscation? In my experience it did not, but maybe I have set it up incorrectly?

Comment: I think what you're wanting to do is select the appropriate 'Emit Debugging Symbols' relative to what works in your specific setup.  If you're shipping a release version, you might consider optimization, sequence points from MSIL if there's no default PDB generated, and sequence from PDB if you have an unobfuscated pdb generated.  Try the options and the one that works is obviously the one you need.  If there's no optimization because it's a debug assembly, you'd choose 'No JIT Optimization' and the appropriate sequence points for your setup.

Comment: If I recall, PDB is different from the "debug symbols" that Windows Store Apps use

Comment: I think it uses the same debug symbols, it's just a matter of how you obtain them.  I could be wrong.  Perhaps you have to [modify the output packaged library and its pdb symbols](http://www.codesmartnothard.com/2013/05/06/StoringWindows8StoreAppsBinariesAndDebugSymbolsInTeamFoundationService.aspx), but I'll be honest, it's not an area I work with.